# dynamic link library c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, hyperlink, dllexport

I was writing a c++ library and testing it, I compiled it using command line tools without using any ide, when I compiled the library and the test program no error found, but when i run the program it sometimes generate an error and sometimes work correctly, when i get an error it is:
"The specified procedure could not be found"
I used dllexport in my library header and pragma comment (lib,...) to link in my test
and my compile command is like thiis:

```
cl -o library.dll quaternion.cpp /link /DLL
cl program.cpp
```

the complete run output:

```
q = 10 + 10 i + 10 j + 10 k
p = 1 + 1 i + 1 j + 1 k
testing *= operator:
q = -20 + 20 i + 20 j + 20 k
testing * operator:
q = -20 + 20 i + 20 j + 20 k
testing /= operator:
q = 10
testing / operator:
q = 10
testing += operator:
q = 11 + 11 i + 11 j + 11 k
testing + operator:
q = 11 + 11 i + 11 j + 11 k
testing -= operator:
q = 9 + 9 i + 9 j + 9 k
testing - operator:
q = 9 + 9 i + 9 j + 9 k
testing = operator:
q = 1 + 1 i + 1 j + 1 k
testing ^ operator:
power 2:
q = -200 + 200 i + 200 j + 200 k
power 3:
q = -80000 - 80000 i - 80000 j - 80000 k
power 4:
q = -1.28e+010 + 1.28e+010 i + 1.28e+010 j + 1.28e+010 k
power 0:
q = 1
testing norm function:
||q|| = 20
```

and the error run output:

```
q = 10 + 10 i + 10 j + 10 k
p = 1 + 1 i + 1 j + 1 k
testing *= operator:
q = -20 + 20 i + 20 j + 20 k
testing * operator:
q = -20 + 20 i + 20 j + 20 k
testing /= operator:
q = 10
testing / operator:
q = 10
testing += operator:
q = 11 + 11 i + 11 j + 11 k
testing + operator:
error!The specified procedure could not be found.
```

### and here is my code:

### quaternion.h

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#ifndef QUATERNION_H
#define QUATERNION_H

#ifdef EXPORTING_DLL
    #define DllExport  __declspec( dllexport )
#else
    #define DllExport  __declspec( dllimport )
#endif
using namespace std;

class Quaternion
{
    public:
        float X, Y, Z, W;
        DllExport Quaternion();
        DllExport Quaternion(const Quaternion& orig);
        DllExport Quaternion(float x, float y, float z, float w);
        DllExport ~Quaternion();

        //base math
        DllExport Quaternion & operator +(const Quaternion &q);
        DllExport Quaternion & operator +=(const Quaternion &q);

        DllExport Quaternion & operator -(const Quaternion &q);
        DllExport Quaternion & operator -=(const Quaternion &q);

        DllExport Quaternion & operator *(const Quaternion &q);
        DllExport Quaternion & operator *=(const Quaternion &q);

        DllExport Quaternion & operator /(const Quaternion &q);
        DllExport Quaternion & operator /=(const Quaternion &q);

        DllExport Quaternion & operator =(const Quaternion &q);

        DllExport Quaternion & operator ^(int i);

        //aditional functions
        DllExport double Norm();// ||q||
        DllExport string ToString();
    private:
};

#endif
```

### quaternion.cpp:

```
#include "quaternion.h"

Quaternion::Quaternion()
{
    X = 0;
    Y = 0;
    Z = 0;
    W = 0;
}

Quaternion::Quaternion(const Quaternion& orig) 
{
    X = orig.X;
    Y = orig.Y;
    Z = orig.Z;
    W = orig.W;
}


Quaternion::Quaternion(float x, float y, float z, float w)
{
    X = x;
    Y = y;
    Z = z;
    W = w;
}

Quaternion::~Quaternion()
{

}

Quaternion & Quaternion::operator +(const Quaternion &q)
{
    return Quaternion(X + q.X, Y + q.Y, Z + q.Z, W + q.W);
}

Quaternion & Quaternion::operator +=(const Quaternion &q)
{
    *this = *this + q;
    return *this;
}

Quaternion & Quaternion::operator -(const Quaternion &q)
{
    return Quaternion(X - q.X, Y - q.Y, Z - q.Z, W - q.W);
}
Quaternion & Quaternion::operator -=(const Quaternion &q)
{
    *this = *this - q;
    return *this;
}

Quaternion & Quaternion::operator *(const Quaternion &q)
{
    return Quaternion(
        X * q.X - Y * q.Y - Z * q.Z - W * q.W,
        X * q.Y + Y * q.X - Z * q.W + W * q.Z,
        X * q.Z + Y * q.W + Z * q.X - W * q.Y,
        X * q.W - Y * q.Z + Z * q.Y + W * q.X
    );
}
Quaternion & Quaternion::operator *=(const Quaternion &q)
{   
    *this = *this * q;
    return *this;
}

Quaternion & Quaternion::operator /(const Quaternion &q)
{
    float square = q.X * q.X + q.Y * q.Y + q.Z * q.Z + q.W * q.W;
    return Quaternion(
        (X * q.X + Y * q.Y + Z * q.Z + W * q.W) / square,
        (X * q.Z - Y * q.X - Z * q.W + W * q.Z) / square,
        (X * q.Y + Y * q.W - Z * q.X - W * q.Y) / square,
        (X * q.W - Y * q.Z + Z * q.Y - W * q.X) / square
    );
}
Quaternion & Quaternion::operator /=(const Quaternion &q)
{
    *this = *this / q;
    return *this;
}

Quaternion & Quaternion::operator =(const Quaternion &q)
{
    X = q.X;
    Y = q.Y;
    Z = q.Z;
    W = q.W;
    return *this;
}

Quaternion & Quaternion::operator ^(int i)
{
    if(i ==0)
    {
        X = 1;
        Y = Z = W = 0;
    }
    else
        while(i > 1)
        {
            *this *= *this;
            i--;
        }
    return *this;
}


double Quaternion::Norm()
{
    return sqrt(X * X + Y * Y + Z * Z + W * W);
}

string Quaternion::ToString()
{
    string result;
    stringstream ss (stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
    ss<<X;
    if(Y>0)
        ss<<" + "<<Y<<" i";
    else  if(Y<0)
        ss<<" - "<<-Y<<" i";
    if(Z>0)
        ss<<" + "<<Z<<" j";
    else if(Z<0)
        ss<<" - "<<-Z<<" j";
    if(W>0)
        ss<<" + "<<W<<" k";
    else if(W<0)
        ss<<" - "<<-W<<" k";
    result = ss.str();
    return result;
}
```

### program.cpp

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "quaternion.h"
#include <exception>
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"library")
#pragma comment(lib,"user32")
#pragma comment(lib,"kernel32")
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    try
    {
        cout<<"Quaternion class library unit test:\n";

        Quaternion p = Quaternion(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Quaternion q = Quaternion(10, 10, 10, 10);
        cout<<"q = "<<q.ToString()<<"\n";
        cout<<"p = "<<p.ToString()<<"\n";

        cout<<"testing *= operator:\n";
        q *= p;
        cout<<"q = "<<q.ToString()<<"\n";
        q = Quaternion(10, 10, 10, 10);

        cout<<"testing * operator:\n";
        q = q * p;
        cout<<"q = "<<q.ToString()<<"\n";
        q = Quaternion(10, 10, 10, 10);

        cout<<"testing /= operator:\n";
        q /= p;
        cout<<"q = "<<q.ToString()<<"\n";
        q = Quaternion(10, 10, 10, 10);

        cout<<"testing / operator:\n";
        q = q / p;
        cout<<"q = "<<q.ToString()<<"\n";
        q = Quaternion(10, 10, 10, 10);

        cout<<"testing += operator:\n";
        q += p;
        cout<<"q = "<<q.ToString()<<"\n";
        q = Quaternion(10, 10, 10, 10);

        cout<<"testing + operator:\n";
        q = q + p;
        cout<<"q = "<<q.ToString()<<"\n";
        q = Quaternion(10, 10, 10, 10);

        cout<<"testing -= operator:\n";
        q -= p;
        cout<<"q = "<<q.ToString()<<"\n";
        q = Quaternion(10, 10, 10, 10);

        cout<<"testing - operator:\n";
        q = q - p;
        cout<<"q = "<<q.ToString()<<"\n";
        q = Quaternion(10, 10, 10, 10);

        cout<<"testing = operator:\n";
        q = p;
        cout<<"q = "<<q.ToString()<<"\n";
        q = Quaternion(10, 10, 10, 10);

        cout<<"testing ^ operator:\n";
        cout<<"power 2:\n";
        q = q ^ 2;
        cout<<"q = "<<q.ToString()<<"\n";
        q = Quaternion(10, 10, 10, 10);

        cout<<"power 3:\n";
        q = q ^ 3;
        cout<<"q = "<<q.ToString()<<"\n";
        q = Quaternion(10, 10, 10, 10);

        cout<<"power 4:\n";
        q = q ^ 4;
        cout<<"q = "<<q.ToString()<<"\n";
        q = Quaternion(10, 10, 10, 10);

        cout<<"power 0:\n";
        q = q ^ 0;
        cout<<"q = "<<q.ToString()<<"\n";
        q = Quaternion(10, 10, 10, 10);

        cout<<"testing norm function:\n";
        cout<<"||q|| = "<<q.Norm()<<"\n";   
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        TCHAR errmsg[512];
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,0,::GetLastError(),0,errmsg,1024,NULL);
        cout<< "error!"<<errmsg;
    }
}
```

I didn't find any help in the msdn or the cl and link options.
I hope any one can help.

here is a link to the current version
http://jumbofiles.com/rh0j46ibyt56

Comment: +1 for a well asked question with enough code for people to look into it properly.

Comment: -1 for not providing the minimal code needed to understand the question.

Comment: And it might be a bad idea to write `using namespace std` in a header

Answer (score 5):

This isn't an answer to your problem but this code has a problem -

```
Quaternion & Quaternion::operator +(const Quaternion &q)
 {     
    return Quaternion(X + q.X, Y + q.Y, Z + q.Z, W + q.W); 
}
```

you are creating an temporary object then returning a reference to it. By the time you use the reference in the caller, it will have been destructed. You need to not return a reference.

edit: And as pointed out below, this may corrupt your stack so could well be the cause of your problem.

Comment: +1. This is actually likely to be the issue. Using that reference to the temp might corrupt the stack, causing the code to go wondering where some procedure cannot be found.

Comment: Yes, true. It certainly could be the problem.

Comment: I fixed this problem and I return const quaternion now but the main problem still exist

Comment: Did you fix it for all the ones that return a reference to a temporary not just that one? There doesn't look anything immediately wrong that I cna notice but I can't tets the code right now (

Comment: I'll try compiling it if nobody beats me to it, but it will be at least 12 hours before I can do so.